# how to set css for Zend form?

Tags: css, zend-framework, zend-form

I m New to Zend framework and I have created a login form in PHP and I want to set Its css style but I don't know how to set it.

Please Suggest some code or link.....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are creating your form elements you have to give them names:

```
$form->addElement('text', 'username');
$form->addElement('password', 'password');
$form->addElement('submit', 'submit');
```

These become the ids of the elements. You can target these elements using CSS selectors just like any other element:

```
input#username,
input#password
{
    width:200px
}
input#username
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

You can also give the form a name.

Another method is to give your form elements classes:

```
$element->setAttrib('class', 'username');
```

As you become more experienced with ZF you may want to start looking at [form element decorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html). These allow you to show error messages, labels, and extra divs or whatever around your form elements.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against being too specific with styling in your forms.  You'll notice that most of the built-in decorators are fairly basic markup.  Once you start mixing in css classes your forms become too view-layer heavy and it makes them difficult to reuse.  For example in a mobile vs. full browser context.

Instead, echo your form inside of a div and use css to style child elements.

```
<div class="login-form">
    <?php echo $form ?>
</div>

div.login-form input[type=text] { width: 200px; }
```